# Delete trigger on Many-to-Many Table

Tags: sql-server

Hello i have to create a trigger that will help me delete a User.

Example: DELETE FROM Users WHERE Users.Id = 1

I have tables that reference to the Users table, and when i try to delete from the other tables before i delete from the Users table i get this:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_UsersChats_Users". The conflict occurred in database "cd8eb179-8ec2-41ae-aa28-46e1571ca2bf", table "dbo.UsersChats", column 'UserId'.
```

[My Db diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lws7B.png)

My code so far: http://pastebin.com/45H1WGSr

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to edit the post to add [SOLVED] to the title and the answer in the question. If you found a solution and you'd like to share it with future readers, do so properly by writing an answer in the space below provided for that purpose. For more info, see [Can I answer my own question here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking of doing that bu it warned me if i was sure i want to answer my own question, il do that now tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a stored procedure or series of queries that deletes from the parent table, then deletes from each child table, or you can set CASCADE DELETE on the relationships so they do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to solve this just now with just a small change

I just used "INSTEAD OF DELETE" rather than "FOR DELETE" and it all worked nicely.

Comment: That works, but most database people would tell you not to use triggers.  They work fine, but you tend to forget they're there, and can be left scratching your head wondering why certain things are breaking when you make changes, or why data is disappearing mysteriously.  Just a suggestion...

Comment: @PhillipXT: The same could also be said of the cascading foreign key. Both it and the trigger are "action at a distance". That said, there's a time and a place for everything. For this use case, I like (in order of preference): a stored procedure that deletes the user, a trigger on the user table, a cascading foreign key.

Comment: I agree Ben... I never use triggers or cascades myself, but sometimes I do suggest the cascade to other people who aren't technically advanced enough to figure out how to write a stored procedure.